# React Native navigation with StackNavigator not working

Tags: react-native, redux

I have taken a big hustle on this.
I am trying to navigate to another page..

**there is the page i am coming from**

CandidateList.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import {Text, View, Button, ListView} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {candidatesFetch, candidatePreviewNavigate} from '../actions/CandidatesActions';
//import {ListItem} from '../common'
import ListItemRedux from './ListItemREDUX'
//import {ListItemConst} from './ListItemConst'
//import ListItem from './ListItem'


class CandidatesList extends Component {

  //var navi = {};

  constructor(props) {

         super(props);
         console.log(this.props);
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const {navigate} = navigation;
    //navi = navigate
    console.log("This naviate is" , navigation);


    return {
      title      : <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center', color: "#206C97", fontWeight: 'normal'}}>List of
        Candidates</Text>,
      headerRight: (<Button title="Add New Candidate"
                            onPress={() => navigate('CandidatesForm')}/>),
      headerLeft : null
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.candidatesFetch();
    this.createDataSource(this.props)
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.createDataSource(nextProps)
  }

  createDataSource({candidates}) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(candidates)
  }

  //onListedItemPress() {
  //  const {navigate} = this.props;
  //  this.props.candidatePreviewNavigate({navigate});
  //}




  renderRow(candidate, navigation) {


    const  onCandidatePress=()=>{

      const {navigate} = navigation;
      console.log("The nav oooo is =>" , navigation);
      this.props.candidatePreviewNavigate({navigate}).bind(this);

    }
    return <ListItemRedux onPress={()=>{onCandidatePress()}} candidate={candidate}/>;
  }

  render() {
    //const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    //console.log(this.props);
    //console.log("This is render navigate", this.props);
    return (
      <View>
        <ListView
          enableEmptySections
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
        <View style={{margin: 10}}>
          <Button title="Add new Candidate"
                  onPress={() => navigate('CandidatesForm')}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }


}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {

  const candidates = _.map(state.fetch, (val, uid) => {
    return {...val, uid};
  });
  const {navigate} = props.navigation

  return {candidates, navigate};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {candidatesFetch, candidatePreviewNavigate})(CandidatesList);
```

My problem is in the function

```
 renderRow(candidate, navigation) {


    const  onCandidatePress=()=>{

      const {navigate} = navigation;
      console.log("The nav oooo is =>" , navigation);
      this.props.candidatePreviewNavigate({navigate}).bind(this);

    }
    return <ListItemRedux onPress={()=>{onCandidatePress()}} candidate={candidate}/>;
  }
```

The navigation that is passed in is very odd 
When i log i get sometinh like **s1**

Here ar the logs

> > 09-07 16:21:33.240  3817  6762 W ReactNativeJS: (Saw setTimeout with
> >     duration 3299045ms)
> >
> > 09-07 16:21:39.825  3817  6762 I ReactNativeJS: 'The nav oooo is =>',
> >     's1'
> >
> > 09-07 16:21:39.826  3817  6762 E ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an
> >     object (evaluating '_this2.props.candidatePreviewNavigate')
> >
> > 09-07 16:22:36.893  3817  6762 W ReactNativeJS: Setting a timer for a
> >     long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and
> >     correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and
> >     timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See
> >     https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
> >
> > 09-07 16:22:36.893  3817  6762 W ReactNativeJS:
>
> (Saw setTimeout with duration 154116ms)
>
> 09-07 16:25:11.020  3817  6762 W ReactNativeJS: Setting a timer for a
>   long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and
>   correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and
>   timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
>
> 09-07 16:25:11.020  3817  6762 W ReactNativeJS: (Saw setTimeout with
>   duration 429359ms)

This line is where I log in order to see the **navigation object**

```
The nav oooo is =>', 's1'
```

But the error keeps on insisting :

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.candidatePreviewNavigate')
```

How do i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const  onCandidatePress=()=>{
          const {navigate} = navigation;
          console.log("The nav oooo is =>" , navigation);
          this.props.candidatePreviewNavigate({navigate});
        }
     renderRow(candidate, navigation) {
        return <ListItemRedux onPress={()=>{onCandidatePress()}} candidate={candidate}/>;
      }
```